# The special linear group $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is its own commutator

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Let $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrix with determinant one. Where can I find a proof that $[SL_n(\mathbb{R}),SL_n(\mathbb{R})]=SL_n(\mathbb{R})$? I've seen this result mentioned in several places, but couldn't find a proof.

For reference, the commutator $[SL_n(\mathbb{R}),SL_n(\mathbb{R})]$ is defined as the group generated by the set of all elements of the form $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, with $a,b\in SL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Wouldn't elements of the commutator have zero trace? Thus for example, the commutator wouldn't contain the identity matrix. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @User8128 I don't think so, the commutator is the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.

Comment: oh I see. I was under the impression that the commutator was the elements of the form $[A,B] =AB -BA$. I suppose I was viewing $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ as an associative algebra rather than a group (and hence using the wrong bracket). Otherwise it's possible I'm just completely mistaken.

Comment: @User8128 I'll add the definition to my question to avoid future misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this makes $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ what's called a perfect group:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group

A proof of this fact can be found at GroupProps:
https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group_is_perfect