# Show the group $SL_2(R)$ is can be created by commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I want to show that $SL_2(R) = [SL_2(R),SL_2(R)]$.

I reduced the problem only show that the matrices $A=\{(1,x),(0,1)\}, B=\{(1,0),(x,1)\}, C=\{(x,0),(0,\frac {1}{x})\}$

are products of commutators.

How can I show this?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372936/the-special-linear-group-textsl-n-mathbbr-is-its-own-commutator). Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762210/commutator-group-of-gl-2r-is-sl-2r?rq=1).

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of [The special linear group $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is its own commutator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372936/the-special-linear-group-textsl-n-mathbbr-is-its-own-commutator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $S\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
 S = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&\ \\
 a&1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 x&\ \\
 \ &x^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&b\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
    or
    \begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
 S &= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \ &1\\
 1&\ 
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&\ \\
 a&1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 x&\ \\
 \ &-x^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&b\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}\\
 &=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&a\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \ &-1\\
 1&\ 
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 x&\ \\
 \ &x^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&b\ \\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation*}
for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^*$. Moreover, we have
    \begin{equation*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \ &-1\\
 1&\ 
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&-2\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&1\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&\ \\
 1&1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1\\
 \ & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
    and
    \begin{equation*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 x&\ \\
 \ &x^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&1\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&\ \\
 x-1&1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&-x^{-1}\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&\ \\
 x-x^2&1
 \end{pmatrix}.
 \end{equation*}
Hence $\mathrm{SL}_2({\mathbb{R}})$ is generated by transvections (matrices of form \begin{pmatrix}1&y\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} or \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ y&1\end{pmatrix} for some $y\in\mathbb{R}$).

Now it suffices to prove that all transvections are commutators. Note that
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&-x\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 a&\ \\
 \ &a^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&x\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 a^{-1}&\ \\
 \ &a
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&(a^2-1)x\\
 \ &1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$. This implies every transvection is a commutator (similar for lower triangular transvections). Thus the commutator subgroup is indeed the whole group, because all transvections generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: It looks like this works, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

But that is not true, since $SL_2(R)$ is not closed under the bracket. Do you mean the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(R)=\{A \in M_2(R) | tr(A)=0\}$? Or is your first equation wrong?

Comment: The "bracket" $[A,B]$ here is the commutator for groups, i.e., $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$, and not the Lie bracket $AB-BA$.