# Are Gl(2,R) and Sl(2,R) isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Gl(2,R) and Sl(2,R) are both infinite groups, though Sl(2,R) is a proper subgroup of Gl(2,R). So is it possible to get such isomorphism

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Their centers are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ and $\{1,-1\}$ respectively. So, they cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: @ultralegend5385, I was thinking of the function, but I couldn't get any such

Comment: This question can be closed for a thousand reasons, but not because it is a duplicate of the question in the above link. If someone were to suggest comparing the commutator subgroups of these groups, it turns out that this question is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251556/) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762210/commutator-group-of-operatornamegl-2-mathbbr-is-operatornamesl-2-m?noredirect=1&lq=1) questions?